# Team Foundation ASP.NET if Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfsbuild

I'm working on TFS. My question is how can I use if condition in Default.aspx?

This is my code:

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Fields['Severity'].Value")%>
```

When I try

```
<%!String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(
    Container.DataItem, "Fields['Severity'].Value").ToString()) ? "a" : "b";%>
```

it is not working. How can I fix it if

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Fields['Severity'].Value")%>
```

is empty value will be " ". If workitemtype is Change the request severity will be empty, if workitemtype is Bug - severity can be Medium Critical low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional operator is correct, you don't need a terminating semi-colon(;) at the last though. This should work:-

```
'<%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,
                 "Fields['Severity'].Value").ToString()) ? "a" : "b" %>'
```

**Update:**

Your new exception might be occurringbecause `ToString()` will throw a null reference exception if the value is `null`. You can type-cast it to avoid this:-

```
'<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,
           "Fields['Severity'].Value")) ? String.Empty : 
            DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Fields['Severity'].Value").ToString() %>'
```

Comment: its not working this code error is Container does not exists  in the current context

Comment: @ferfeit - My Bad! You need a `#` for data bind expressions. Try now.

Comment: this time different error  Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. actually i want to if DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Fields['Severity'].Value") is empty result will be empty otherwise result should be this DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Fields['Severity'].Value")

Comment: @ferfeit - Glad to help u :) You can accept the answer :)

Comment: @ferfeit - Hey You can't upvote but you can accept the answer. Simply click on the Tick symbol :)